# How to search text on running program output

Tags: ruby, terminal, zsh

### foo.rb

```
i = 1
while 1
    puts i
    i = i + 1
    sleep(1)
end
```

### No work

I have confirmed:

`$ ruby foo.rb | less`
`$ ruby foo.rb | less -F`
`$ ruby foo.rb | vim -R`
`$ ruby foo.rb | tail -f`

All code not work. I want to search text on the terminal

I use OSX Yosemite and `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

This is a buffering issue. Your ruby is waiting to flush. If you loop to, say, 3, instead of eternity, you’ll see some output — but not until the complete run. Here’s an example based on yours:

```
% <latent.rb
i = 1
# STDOUT.sync = true
while i < 3  # making loop finite
    puts i
    # STDOUT.flush
    i = i + 1
    sleep(1)
end

% ruby latent.rb |grep .  # match anything
<waiting ... and finally all at once>
1
2
%
```

If you uncomment either the `flush` or `sync`, you’ll see output right away. Further explanation of the buffering is [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/208856).

You could also change the behavior by using `unbuffer` (part of expect package):

```
% unbuffer ruby latent.rb |grep .  # match anything
<immediate output>
```